# How can I carry over attributes from a GIS .shp to a SnakeGrid MicroStation .dgn, using FME?

Tags: shapefile, fme-form, microstation, dgn

I have the SnakeGrid projector so can convert coordinate systems but can't seem to carry the attributes over (I have tried AttribueManager and AttributeCopier).

Also, can I input several .shp and run a batch to export as .dgn with attributes carried over?

Comment: Would like to help but I suck at DGN. For a quick response ask the question at the safe software forum (https://knowledge.safe.com/questions/index.html). Lots of active FME compared to SE.

Comment: We need more information to help you. Wich writer format are you using? Wich kind of database are you using (access, oracle..)?

Comment: @cag - I am using a DGNV8 writer with an esri Shapefile reader. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the FME DGN writer ensure that the option to write tags is set to on:

[image: add tags to DGN]

Attribute information can then be written as tags (see this [document](https://knowledge.safe.com/articles/1538/writing-microstation-dgn-tags-with-fme.html)).
Note in Bentley Microstation Connect that tags are deprecated and you may need to upgrade to item types (search ribbon>item types>Utilities>Upgrade Tag Sets).

Regarding batch processing - use a [workspace runner](https://www.safe.com/transformers/workspace-runner/).

Comment: Thank you @JimT. I have set this up using a batch process so it reads all .shp in an input folder by using '*/shp@ in the reader. This works but carries over all attributes from all .shp, regardless of whether they exist in a individual .shp. Do you know a way to only carry over the specific attributes from each individual .shp into the output .dgn?

Comment: It sounds like you need dynamic schema reading - though I suggest you start a new question (showing your current workflow/method in some detail) rather than asking new ones in the comments.